# using d3.scaleOrdinal troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm making a parallel plot (see: https://www.data-to-viz.com/graph/parallel.html) and need each of my lines to be different colors based on the country they're assigned too. I'm working in JS d3.

This is the scale I have right now:

```
var ColorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(countries).range(d3.schemeDark2);
```

But I don't think the issue is here since when I check each country has a different color code.
I have a function to make lines that gets passed the color, and then here's that code:

```
d3.select("g#lines")
.append("path")
.datum(data)
.attr("class", "line")
.attr("d", LineGenerator)
.style("stroke", Color);
```

When I inspect the page, stroke is always set to rgb(102, 102, 102) which I believe is grey. I don't think I have a css rule overwriting it.

Here's a link to the full code on codesandbox if you're interested: https://codesandbox.io/s/csc-160-project-forked-5bx01

This is being written in the "parallelplot.js" file. The "plot.html" file is where it's drawn. The data is from "DataTransposed.csv"

Comment: The problem happens because you're passing 6 arguments to the make line function, the sixth is the colour and the fifth the scale. The function only takes 5 arguments, the 5th of which is supposed to be the color, so you've got mismatched arguments.

Comment: Oh thanks for the catch! I didn't notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of changes you need to make, first the function you defined to draw the lines only takes 5 params and you are passing both the scale and the color value, it takes the first of them (scale) which is the always the same therefore your output is always the same color.

```
var MakeLine = function (data, country, xScale, yScale, Color) {
```

Second since you probably are going to have more than 2 countries you don't want to create intermediate variables just send the evaluation

```
var ColorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(countries).range(d3.schemeDark2);
  MakeAxes(graph, margins, xScale, yScale);

  d3.select("svg#linegraph")
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", "lines")
    .attr("transform", MakeTranslateString(margins.left, margins.top));

  MakeLine(data, "Argentina", xScale, yScale, ColorScale("Argentina"));
  MakeLine(data, "Egypt", xScale, yScale, ColorScale("Egypt"));
```

Even better if you pass the country name as a variable when you go through data to have a single statement doing everything.

Comment: Oh thanks for the catch on the parameters! I would also love to put it in a loop, but I don't know to do that in JS unfortunately. (My brain tells me to do it like for country in countries, call function with country as arg, but I don't know the syntax or if that works in JS and my teacher suggested I just call it... a lot. Not ideal but there it is)